# key as variable navigating jsonp object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

i hope my title is somewhat correct since i am not sure how to name what i am trying to do...

```
"modifiers":{"agility":{"type":"attribute","displayname":"agi","value":46}}
```

is part of a jsonp callback i get from [here](http://data.soe.com/json/get/eq2/item/584991609,2293972098?callback=?).
i am trying to log/access the `value` of different `modifiers`

it works if i use:

```
console.log(item1.modifiers.agility.value); /*item1 being item_list[0]*/
```

BUT what if dont know the contents of `modifiers` in other calls (could be `strength` or `wisdom` or both). how do i access them?

the closest i got was this:

```
    for (var x in item1.modifiers){
        console.log(x);
        console.log(item1.modifiers.x.value);
    }
```

`x` correctly logs as `agility` but its not valid in the statement to log `value`

is there a way to put a variable in a "call" like that? if not how else would i solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript objects are just hashes and can be accessed as such:

```
item1.modifiers[x].value
```

should work

Explanation:

Any object in JavaScript is just a dictionary/hash:

```
var x = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
x.a # = 1;
x['a'] # = 1;
```

So in your case you could rewrite the whole thing as:

```
item1['modifiers'][x]['value']
```

Comment: Thought I was going to get some rep score on this question... Darn you!

Comment: thanks a lot... i am web-teaching myself, have some crazy gaps in my knowledge and a hard time finding solutions for stuff i cant name =)